# Webview not showing some text like symbol of maths below marshmallow devices

Tags: android, webview

Some mathematical symbols or equations are not showing on android webview.
But these are showing on above lollipop and web browser. 
These are copied from ms word file. Content is following:
The capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor is 12μF. If the distance between the plates is doubled and area is halved, then new capacitance will be

Comment: How do you set the data to webview . with url or texts ?

Comment: I have data in string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting data with contents then you have to add

```
webView.loadData(texts, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

`loadData` will work in most of the devices but in `Gingerbread`, you have to add

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, texts, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: already applied above settings, but it is not working for some special symbols which i already given in question.

Comment: even i created an html page on android studio in raw folder then run it on browser but having same problem. But when i create it on any other place like in folder of drive of my system than run that html page, it works perfectly.

Comment: 12μF is not visible in android webview